# In what language does Jango Fett speak to Boba Fett in Attack of The Clones?

Tags: star-wars, languages

In Attack of The Clones, there's a point when Obi Wan meets Jango Fett. During the middle of the meeting, Jango says something in what sounded like another language to his son Boba, probably because he didn't want Obi Wan to understand what he was saying. What language was he speaking in? In Legends, it seems like it could be Mandalorian, but that doesn't make sense, because Jango isn't Mandalorian in canon. Does any canon material say what language that was?

Comment: Dose subtitles tho...

Comment: @Worse_Username "I was recruited by a man called dinosaur on the moons of bunker" LOL

Comment: What Disney calls "Legends" is canon in George Lucas's vision.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The film's [junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(junior_novelization)) just says that it's a "coded" language, presumably something that Jango has taught his son to allow them to communicate without worrying about being overheard

> *There was none, nor did Jango Fett move a centimeter out of Obi-Wan’s
> line of sight, and when the Jedi tried to subtly alter his angle to
> gain a view, **Jango said, in a coded language, “Boba, close the door.”***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones (junior novelization)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

This aligns nicely with the description of it as "***Fett Code***" in this video from LucasFilm

---

Interestingly the Scholastic Young Reader book [Boba Fett: The Fight to Survive](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett:_The_Fight_to_Survive) (which also contains the scene) indicates that it's plain ***Huttese***.

> *“Boba, close the door,” said Jango in Huttese, a language they both
> knew well.*
>
> *Boba did what his father asked, never taking his eyes off the Jedi. He
> wanted him to feel his hate.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Boba Fett: The Fight to Survive](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett:_The_Fight_to_Survive)</sup></sub>

And the screenplay at the rear of the [Art of Star Wars II, Attack of the Clones](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones) factbook agrees with this.

[image]

That being said, this doesn't make a lot of sense since it's quite likely that a well-educated Jedi would know at least a smattering of that language, hence why they seem to have changed it.

---

As pointed out on the excellent [Wermo's Guide website](http://www.completewermosguide.com/mandalorian.html), the actual phrase (as seen in the official subtitling) is just an [argot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argot) for "close the door" with the words reversed and jumbled a bit.

> Uh Boba, rood eht so-heeck

Comment: Obviously, when the hutts didn't speak, Jango taught them his code language and they appropriated it as "huttese".

Comment: Coded Huttesse, perhaps?

Comment: Why would it be important for them to hide this piece of information? It might have as well been huttese.

Answer (score -1):

It is different in different versions of the story.  In one it's "a coded language," in another, it's Huttese, in another, Mandalorian.  They probably never officially decided what exactly the language they were using was.

Comment: In which is it Mandalorian?